# Wordpress and SQL, compare condition

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I wanna compare "postType",

```
<input name="postType" value="" id="postType" required>
```

with a column in my DB called "post_type" (from table wp_posts). So, I just wanna the results with matches the input with the value in post_type column. I don't know if I can do a for each or put a SQL statement. Examples:

```
if($_POST["postType"] == "page") {
    //results
}
```

So, if I put "page" in my input it returns the correct results.

What I've done to the general case:

```
$term = $_POST["postType"];
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT count(ID) FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = '".$term."')");
foreach($result as $resultX) {
    if($_POST["postType"] == $resultX) {
        //results
    }
}
```

But it is not working

Comment: Can you elaborate on "but it is not working"? Are you getting an error? The wrong result?

Comment: You seem to have added a stray ')' in your SQL, which should cause an error.

Comment: You're retrieving a numeric value with `SELECT count(ID)` but it looks like you're expecting an array.

Comment: you haven't provided a `type="..."` for your input field, and your sql/php is wide open for [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). Have you done any basic debugging, like `var_dump($_POST)` to see what the script is receiving?

Comment: thanks for the sql injection advice. i did var_dump, and i can't get the resultX items. Ignore the ')', I've corrected it. The wrong results is not showing what i want (it shows nothing). Yeah, count(ID) is wrong. How can i change to return strings from post_type and compare?